# Weird behaviour for Python is_integer from floor

Tags: python, math, logging, floor

When checking if a floor is an int, the recommend method would be `is_integer`:

However, I get a weird behaviour with the results of the `log` function:

```
print(log(9,3));                        #2.0
print((log(9,3)).is_integer());         #True

print((log(243,3)));                    #5.0
print((log(243,3)).is_integer());       #False
```

Furthermore:

```
print((int) (log(9,3)));    #2
print((int) (log(243,3)));  #4
```

Is this normal?

Comment: You are not writing c, print(int(log(243,3))), also you should read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken

Comment: Why i shouldn't write it like this?

Answer (score 4):

`log(243,3)` simply doesn't give you exactly 5:

```
>>> '%.60f' % log(243,3)
'4.999999999999999111821580299874767661094665527343750000000000'
```

As [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/math.html#math.log) say, `log(x, base)` is *"calculated as log(x)/log(base)"*. And neither `log(243)` nor `log(3)` can be represented exactly, and you get rounding errors. Sometimes you're lucky, sometimes you're not. Don't count on it.

Answer (score 3):

When you want to compare float numbers, use [`math.isclose()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/math.html#math.isclose).

When you want to convert a float number that is close to an integer, use [`round()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#round).

Float numbers are too subject to error for "conventional" methods to be used. Their precision (and the precision of functions like `log`) is too limited, unfortunately. What looks like a 5 may not be an exact 5.

And yes: it is normal. This is not a problem with Python, but with every language I'm aware of (they all use the same underlying representation). Python offers some ways to work around float problems: [`decimal`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/decimal.html) and [`fractions`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/fractions.html). Both have their own drawbacks, but sometimes they help. For example, with `fractions`, you can represent 1/3 without loss of precision. Similarly, with `decimal`, you can represent 0.1 exactly. However, you'll still have problems with `log`, `sqrt`, irrational numbers, numbers that require many digits to be represented and so on.